# Quasar Multi Step Form with validation

Tags: validation, vuejs3, quasar-framework, stepper

I tried to create a multi step form using Vue 3 and Quasar UI framework with validation, i'm using q-stepper component , but i want to validate inputs step by step.

can i use muliple q-form ? or only one ?
Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `QStepper` component and leverage the [internal validation](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#internal-validation) of `QInput` component to achieve this goal. 
Please check my example on codepen https://codepen.io/hoangdng-the-sans/pen/YzLKXaG